# Assign a view controller to a custom .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a custom re-usable XIB that I've created and assigned it a class subclasses from UIView.

- BannerView.xib (file owner set appropriately
- BannerView.h : UIView
- BannerView.m

Here is the initWithFrame:

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if(self) {
self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
}

return self;
}
```

Everything works fine and I am able to init this custom .xib and add this to my VC:

```
BannerView *bannerView = [[BannerView alloc]init];
[_profileContentArea addSubview:bannerView];
```

Although, I would like this custom .xib to have it's own VC and then be able to add as a subview via the VC instead of the above. How would I go about this considering my existing setup at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

your init method is initWithFrame,so you must created BannerView like

```
BannerView *bannerView = [[BannerView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

then you can add to ViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; 

if(self) {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
}

    return self;
}
```

Please notice the initialize steps

`+alloc`: alloc memory
`-init` : initialize necessary properties

You've already get the view object when you call `alloc` and set some properties in `init` or `initWithFrame:`

and when you call

```
self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

The old view object is gone because you've just set a new one which is from xib

why don't you use -[UIViewController initWithNibName:nibBundle:] you can set nib whatever you want

Comment: "why don't you use -[UIViewController initWithNibName:nibBundle:] you can set nib whatever you want "

Could you provide a link to a tutorial maybe that shows how to connect a XIB to its own VC? If not, I can do the above, but do I have to do any additional setup such as changing the class of the XIB to the VC or changing file owners etc.?

Comment: @user1686342 change the file owners, when you create a view controller you can specify a xib you want. 
I am thinking you want reuse your controls, or views. you can try to customize your controls which can be used in other places, try not to layout your customized control/view's subview, let your control do it by layoutsubview or autolayout.  your view controller would be simple. then you can avoid the question you ask.
It's my opinion.